# C++ Inheritance - super.method() Java equivalent

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a superclass called `Animal` with a method called `create` that does:

```
static Animal* Animal::create(const std::string& name)
{
Animal* newAnimal = new Animal();
newAnimal ->name = name;
return newAnimal;

}
```

Now I have a subclass called `Dog`. I want to override the `create` method from `Animal`, but avoid copy and pasting the code that is already in there... I basically want this:

```
static Dog* Dog::create(const std::string& name)
{
Dog* newDog = Animal::create(name); // This is the line that I have trouble with.
newDog->type="dog";
}
```

As I mentioned above, I noticed that C++ doesn't do automatic casting - I come from Java background...

Anyways, I was wondering if this is an acceptable way to fix it and doesn't lead to more headache:

```
  Dog *newDog  = static_cast<Dog *>(Animal::create(name));
```

ADDITIONAL NOTE:
So after reading all the comments and solutions, I guess everyone suggests using constructors. But imagine a case that you are not allowed to modify the Animal class, it has a create method and you want to extend that method. Maybe a more proper way to ask is that: Is it possible to extend the super class create method? Let me know if I am totally off - I am very very very new to c++ so maybe the question is just non-sense in c++ point of view...

Comment: That cast isn't going to work. The dynamic type of `newDog` is `Animal *`. It has to start as a `Dog *` to cast it to a `Dog *`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell me what the proper solution is then?

Comment: Why don't you just use constructors?

Comment: My actual super class "create" method is much more complex than what I have above. And I do need to make sure that all initializations done in Animal::create is also done for Dog::create

Comment: This looks like a job for the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern

Comment: @Kasra, Constructors can also be a lot more complex than this. You can use constructors in conjunction with the template method pattern just fine as well. Perhaps there's just something you thought they couldn't do, but can.

Comment: C++ _does_ do automatic casting, but only where such casting is safe.  The cast you're doing is _100% invalid_, so C++ won't do it automatically.  (Same as `Object o = new Object(); String s = (String)o;` in Java)

Comment: @Kasra `I do need to make sure that all initializations done in Animal::create is also done for Dog::create` All parent classes will have fully initialized by the time the child class constructor starts. So constructors is still the way to go IMHO.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, I added an extra piece of information to the question.

Comment: Where/how is the `type` member data field defined? I assume `newDogtype="dog"` is really a typo for `newDog->type="dog"`?

Comment: Yes that is a typo... I will fix it

Comment: @Kasra. You still haven't answered about where `type` is defined. Also, see my updated answer in case SO didn't send you any notifications.

Comment: "type" is a string member of Animal. I have not included the class definition of Animal for sake of brevity. I just saw your answer and am reading it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use constructors and polymorphism.

```
class Animal
{
  const std::string name;
public:
  explicit Animal(const std::string &name) : name(name) {}
  virtual ~Animal() {}
  virtual std::string type() const = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
  explicit Dog(const std::string &name) : Animal(name) {}
  virtual std::string type() const { return "dog"; }
};
```

If you really don't like the polymorphism for whatever reason, then add a `type` data member in `Animal`, and assign to it in the `Dog::Dog` (Dog constructor).

---

I don't think you can do what you are trying to do without changing how `Animal`s are created. Here's why.

First, here's what `Animal::create` does.

1. Allocates `sizeof Animal` bytes on heap
2. Calls default constructor of `Animal` using that allocated chunk of memory.
3. Sets the `name` field.
4. Returns the pointer to the `Animal` object

Here is what a `Dog::create` function would need to do:

1. Allocate `sizeof Dog` bytes on heap
2. Initialize the `Animal` portion of the new `Dog` object. I think you are trying to reuse the `Animal::create` function for this?
3. Set the `type` field
4. Return the pointer to the `Dog` object

The problem is with step 2 of `Dog::create`. Since `Animal::create` allocates its own memory and you can't pass in a pointer to a `Dog`, there is no way to get `Animal::create` to operate on the memory you allocated in step 1.

That said, depending on the internals of `Animal` and specifically if it is copyable, you *may* be able to hack it as follows, but I'm not sure it would work or even be well-defined

```
static Dog * Dog::create(static Dog* Dog::create(const std::string& name)
{
  Animal *animalTmp = Animal::create(name);
  Dog* newDog = new Dog();   // note that Animal::Animal() c-tor is probably called
  *newDog = *animalTmp;      // you have to be careful about which `operator=` is called here
  delete animalTmp;
  newDog->type="dog";
  return newDog;
}
```

This is completely unmaintainable, ugly as hell, very brittle, and A TERRIBLE IDEA.

Comment: Alright! This is one answer that explains things that were not clear to me. I agree, this is ugly. But it answers my problem - so I now know that it is possible but really ugly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually the solution is to use constructors:

```
#include <string>
class animal {
public: 
    animal();
    animal(std::string name, std::string type);
    virtual ~animal();
private:
    std::string name_;
    std::string type_;
};
animal::animal() 
    :name_("unnamed"), type_("unknown") 
    {}
animal::animal(std::string name, std::string type) 
    :name_(std::move(name)), 
    type_(std::move(type)) 
    {}
animal::~animal() {}
```

and then:

```
class dog : public animal{
public: 
    dog();
    dog (std::string name);
    virtual ~dog ();
};
dog::dog() :animal("","dog") {} //delegate to the animal default constructor
dog::dog(std::string name) :animal(std::move(name), "dog") {} //delegate again
dog::~dog() {}
```

and that's far easier to use:

```
int main() {
    dog fido("fido"); //creates a dog on the stack, _very fast_
};
```

Comment: I know that is an old one. Okay to fix your example? (eg. constructor in header should be `animal(std::string name, std::string type).

Comment: Hi, added some fixes your example. This way, you can just put everything in one file and compile like `g++ -o example example.cpp` -- That would not be c++ like, eg. headerfiles, classfiles. But it's just an example.

Comment: @ThomasKettenbach: Now I see my error! Thanks for fixing it!